# How can I compare values in one array PHP?

Tags: php

I have following array structure. I'd like to get max value in array, and if values in array are same to unset this array.

```
   Array(

        [499670] => Array
            (
                [499670] => 1299.00
                [503410] => 1299.00
                [528333] => 1299.00
                [645862] => 0.00
            )

        [499671] => Array
            (
                [499671] => 1149.00
                [503408] => 1149.00
                [528329] => 1500.00
                [645858] => 0.00
            )

        [499672] => Array
            (
                [499672] => 0.00
                [503406] => 0.00
                [528324] => 0.00
                [645850] => 0.00
            )
)
```

I want to get the following result

```
   Array(

                [499670] => 1299.00 >>> one of values in first array
                [528329] => 1500.00 >>> max value in second array
                {third array was removed, because all values are same}

)
```

Comment: What's your current code? It might just need a small tweak. Which part is giving you trouble?

Comment: Just walk through each array and keep a `maxIndex` and `maxValue` that relate to each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate through your array, use [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/array_unique) to check if all the values are the same. If not, find the max value using [`max()`](http://php.net/max):

```
$result = array();

foreach ($data as $key => $subarr) {
    if (count(array_unique($subarr)) === 1) {
        unset($data[$key]);
    } else {
        $result[] = max($subarr);
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1299.00
    [1] => 1500.00
)
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/123706)

Comment: I believe the `, PHP_EOL` has nothing to do here ;-)

Comment: @swordofpain: That was initially used with the `echo` statement to output them in new lines. But I've edited the answer to use an array instead ;)